# Socket.io How to tell when somebody leaves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sockets, socket.io

I am creating a real-time game with socket.io.  Currently, when somebody leaves, nothing happens.  I would like to somehow notify the server to say who left.  Is there a way to emit something right as a user leaves?  Can I have the server ping everybody every 1000ms or something to tell who's still connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before closing the window/page emit an event containing user detail, on add a event listener to listen to that channel. The event listener could get user detail from message received & show it.

Draft:

```
// server code
socket.on('user_left', function(user){
   // broadcast user to channel 'user_left_group'
});

// browser - for other users
socket.on('user_left_group', function(user){
     // code to show user left
}

// browser - to say I am leaving
socket.emit('user_left', myname);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up using the JQuery .unload() handler to do what you were saying.  Works beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Leave means?

Closing application? Closing Windows? Closing System? Internet Gone? I think all are same

You can use the disconnect event and once a socket disconnects (a socket, not a user, cause Node just knows about sockets) you will have to find out who was the "owner" of that socket and flag him as "disconnected".

But I suggest you must wait for few seconds because the disconnect event will trigger even on page reloads, or navigation to another page.

So as per solution you can create a watcher that runs every X seconds and flags users as disconnected when they don't own any socket or when there is no activity for a long time.

Check Socket.io docs for more details:
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io

> **Socket#disconnect(close:Boolean):Socket**
>
> Disconnects this client. If value of close is true, closes the underlying >connection. Otherwise, it just disconnects the namespace.
>
> **Events**
>
> *disconnect*
>
> Fired upon disconnection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  That would also work, but I ended up using the JQuery .unload() handler to emit the user data right when the page is closed.  Thank you so much for answering thought!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, setting a timeout defeats the object of sockets. They are real time, so as soon as an event is triggered a process is started. Socket.io has an event called disconnect which you can listen to and emit to all users currently connected. For example:

Server

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    const _id = socket.id
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        io.emit('userLeft', {message: _id + ' left the room'}
    })
})
```

Client

```
socket.on('userLeft', function(data) {
    document.querySelector('.notification').innerHTML = data
})
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining how that works!  I couldn't figure out how to make the disconnect part of Sockets work.  I ended up using the JQuery .unload handler then emitting the user's data to a different socket I made.  I'm sure this would have worked, but I found that other solution first.  Thanks for responding, and I'll use this technique in my next project for sure!