# How to tell when a socket actually disconnects

Tags: html, node.js, express, socket.io

`socket.on('disconnect')` doesn't do what I expected. I want to know when a user has left my website, rather than just switched pages. Because currently, moving to a different route on my webpage says that the socket has disconnect yet the user is still on the server.

Is basing user attendance on socket connection a bad idea or should I use HTML instead
I tried `<body onbeforeunload='imLeaving()'>` but that still said the user was disconnecting if they went to a different page

I tried this [Socket.io How to tell when somebody leaves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235551/socket-io-how-to-tell-when-somebody-leaves) but it also gives me "false" disconnects

Am i going about this wrong, or is there something obviously wrong with my code.

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http").Server(app)
const io = require("socket.io")(http)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200)
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(socket.disconnected)
        console.log("disconnect")
    })
});

http.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("Listeneing on *:4000")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. On the client side, define a variable `connection_count`. When application starts, pass it to the `query{}` just like you pass auth token in `auth{}`.
2. Every time a new connection happens, parse query params from `socket.handshake` on server side and increment the var.
3. Every time disconnection event triggers, in the same process decrement the var.
4. When the `var == 0`, write a function that will notify that user has terminated all connections.

**Note:** If an user connects for first time, the value of `var` will be 0, so it will give you false indication that user has left your site, when they are just trying to connect. To prevent such behavior, you can pass some flags with `query{}` that will alter over a cycle.